# CSS loading odd on first view, after page refresh everything is fine?

Tags: css, html

I'm working on a CSS layout for my page, I'm just having a problem. On first page view the navbar loads all out of whack, but after page refresh, everything looks fine, here's an example:

```
Before:
```

[image: Before]

```
After:
```

[image]

I'm not sure why it would be doing this I'm kind of new to CSS, any information would be great thanks!

Here's the CSS:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0px;

}

.navbar-fixed {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0, #eee 85%, #ddd 100%);
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #e5e5e5;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-fixed ul {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-fixed ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar-fixed .logo a {
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 32px;
  letter-spacing: -3px;
  transition:  0.3s;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: orange;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px black;
  margin: 0 2em 0 1em;

}

.navbar-fixed .logo a:hover {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 7px black;
  color: white;
  background: transparent;
}

.navbar-fixed ul.nav {
  float: right;
}

.navbar-fixed ul.nav li a {
  padding: 1em;
  display: block;
  color: #00AAEE;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: solid 0 1px 0 1px transparent;
  transition: 0.5s;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-fixed ul li a:hover, ul li.active a  {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  border-color: #ccc;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
}

.newswindow {
 padding: 1em;
 color: #fff;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
}

.newswindow h2 {
  font-size: 42px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
}

.newswindow p {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: Your before and after are empty...where is the example?

Comment: Even with different browsers? *Always* on the **first** view? Are you sure it's not a caching problem?

Comment: @woz Can't believe I forgot that x.x

Comment: Does it do this regularly? Maybe you just need to hit F5 and do full reload.

Comment: @woz It appears to only be on chrome, safari worked, my native linux browser worked, firefox worked, chrome poops the bed, any idea why? Chrome is a pretty widely used browser so I'd like it to look fine for Chrome too

Comment: Chrome caches more heavily than any browser I know of, so just be sure to hit F5 after making a change. It should look ok after that.

Comment: @woz I'm not sure why, but even after manual clearing of history/cache and hitting F5, it still loads funny the first time

Comment: Only in Chrome? Is clearing your cache the only thing that cause that to happen again?

Answer (score 1):

Some browser specific default styles could be interfering your defined styles. (Inherited styles, default *more specifically defined* styles for certain elements...)

For homogenous behavior in all browsers, use a CSS reset and define all the needed styles properly, not depending on browsers' defaults.

Here is a good source:
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/